# Mysql error Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: mysql, pdo

This is my code. I'm unable to execute it.

This is the error message I get on the `$db->execute();` line:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

```
$query = "UPDATE gateway_devices "
        ."SET coin_lat=:coin_lat, coin_lng=:coin_lng"
        ."WHERE nick_name=:nick_name AND gateway_id=:g_id AND device_id=:d_id";

$db->query($query);
$db->bind(':coin_lat', $coin_lat);
$db->bind(':coin_lng', $coin_lng);
$db->bind(':nick_name', $nick_name);
$db->bind(':g_id', $g_id);
$db->bind(':d_id', $d_id);
$db->execute();
```

Comment: If you print out the `$query`, you'll understand why it doesn't work.  I consider the lack of spaces in a constructed query to be a typographical error and vote to close.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks a ton, it was a simple issue with spaces.

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do was add a space on line 2 before closing the double quote.

this is how the query looks like before and after adding the whitespace.

before - "UPDATE gateway_devices SET coin_lat=:coin_lat, **coin_lng=:coin_lngWHERE** nick_name=:nick_name AND gateway_id=:g_id AND device_id=:d_id"

after - "UPDATE gateway_devices SET coin_lat=:coin_lat, coin_lng=:**coin_lng WHERE** nick_name=:nick_name AND gateway_id=:g_id AND device_id=:d_id"